# Foreach loop through controls that are textbox doesn't return

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I've used this code before in another program, but now I'm having trouble understanding why it won't run the code after my second line.

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) //doesn't run any further
    {
        if ((string)c.Tag == "Filled")
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

I'm either missing some minor little detail or something else is incorrect.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  my textboxes are inside a panel.

Comment: Perhaps you've got no textboxes in the Controls?..

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Did you use a debugger to step through the code? You can examine the values of your variables.

Comment: Have you got a groupbox, panel or other container type in the control which actually contains the text boxes? (i.e. perhaps your text boxes aren't directly under the main control)

Comment: No error, I'm using debugger to step through code.  I tried  (C is Textbox) and get the same results

Comment: My textboxes are inside a panel.

Comment: So you would need to use the Panel's Controls property.

Comment: I have made an [API Proposal: Add Descendants property for Control](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5195) on github.com/dotnet/winforms for iterating controls nested inside other controls as well. If you like it, please upvote it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Control.Controls`, it will only return the controls at the outermost level. It won't recursively descend into any container controls that hold other controls.

If your controls are in another container, you will need to use that container's `.Controls` property instead.

Alternatively you can generalize it by writing a method to recursively return all the controls from the parent and all it's children, like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> AllControls(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control control in container.Controls)
    {
        yield return control;

        foreach (var innerControl in AllControls(control))
            yield return innerControl;
    }
}
```

You can then use that instead of Control.Controls as follows:

```
private void test() // Assuming this is a member of a Form other class derived from Control
{
    var textboxesWithFilledTag = 
        AllControls(this).OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(tb => (string) tb.Tag == "Filled");

    foreach (var textbox in textboxesWithFilledTag)
        Debug.WriteLine(textbox.Text);
}
```

As the comment says, I'm assuming that the `test()` method is a member of your Form or another class derived from Control. If it isn't, you will have to pass the parent control to it:

```
private void test(Control container)
{
    var textboxesWithFilledTag = 
        AllControls(container).OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(tb => (string) tb.Tag == "Filled");

    foreach (var textbox in textboxesWithFilledTag)
        Debug.WriteLine(textbox.Text);
}
```

The following method has identical results to the one above, for reference (and is more readable IMHO):

```
private void test(Control container)
{
    foreach (var textbox in AllControls(container).OfType<TextBox>())
        if ((string)textbox.Tag == "Filled")
            Debug.WriteLine(textbox.Text);
}
```

---

For your code, your button click handler might look something like this:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var c in AllControls(this).OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if ((string) c.Tag == "Filled")
        {
            // Here is where you put your code to do something with Textbox 'c'
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you also need the `AllControls()` method, of course.

Comment: I understand what you're saying up to the first section of code you posted.  So after I use this code, I don't follow what I'm do in my buttons click event.

Comment: @KFP I've added what I think your button click handler would look like to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to do this:

```
foreach ( TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
{
    if ((string)tb.Tag == "Filled")
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Tag isn't a string so I believe you need to add a `.ToString()`, I can't verify this though..

Comment: Good point - but I think there are plenty of options for the OP now :-)

Answer (score 2):

To get **all** controls (not only the direct children of the form) you can use this recursive Linq

```
Func<Control, IEnumerable<Control>> allControls = null;
allControls = c => new Control[] { c }
                   .Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                     .SelectMany(x=>allControls(x)));
```

Now you can filter the TextBoxes

```
var tbs = allControls(this).OfType<TextBox>()
            .Where(t=>(string)t.Tag=="Filled")
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `if (c is TextBox)`.
Furthermore, if you want to know why your code breaks, use try/catch

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use following syntax:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
    if (c is TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting [tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198255.aspx) property from yourself. This is a `string` type of property.so you can try this:

```
if (c.Tag == "Filled")
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

if you want to check that text box is not empty then you can simply try this :

```
if (c.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
{
 Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```