# Function variable calling itself

Tags: c#, recursion

How can you call a `Func` function from itself?

For example:

```
 Func<int, int> f = x => {
      // do stuff
      if (x > 5) { return f(x); }
      // do other stuff
 };
```

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16361037/1906557 ?

Comment: You could modify the function to not need recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dlev**'s answer is fairly straight forward, but you can also do this way:

First declare a delegate type that accepts itself as a parameter:

```
public delegate TResult RecursiveFunc<TParam, TResult>(
    TParam param1, 
    RecursiveFunc<TParam, TResult> func);
```

<sup>NOTE: of course the delegate doesn't have to be generic.</sup>

You can now create your lambda expression like this:

```
RecursiveFunc<int, int> f = (x, g) => {
    // do stuff
    if (x > 5) { return g(x, g); }
    // do other stuff
};

f(123, f); // Invoke recursively
```

Comment: Clever, in an ugly sort of way. I don't know whether to like it or hate it. Good to see alternatives, though.

Answer (score 6):

Simple way to is to create the variable, assign it `null`, and *then* use it in your lambda:

```
Func<int, int> f = null;
f = x => {
    // do stuff
    if (x > 5) { return f(x); }
    // do other stuff
};
```

By the time it comes to actually invoke the delegate in `f`, it will have been assigned to a non-null value.

If you prefer, you can also follow the approach shown in this (theory heavy) [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx).

Comment: +1. link to another Y fixed-point combinator article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx